# GitLab Sidebar Plugin?

Tags: interface, gitlab, sidebar

I just installed GitLab on a local server, and I really liked the lateral navigation bar that incorporates the web interface. Could you tell me if this is a plugin that incorporates all this, or was completely customized for the GitLab interface?

[image: SideBar]

Comment: Could you please, explain what do you want to do?

Comment: I am working on a project and I would like to incorporate a sidebar exactly like this one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [Slidebars by adchsm](https://www.adchsm.com/slidebars/), you can see the available [demos](https://www.adchsm.com/slidebars/demos/), but if you need more functionalities you can lookup the official documentation on [github](https://github.com/adchsm/Slidebars).